# View or hide one report menu based on condition in odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-view

I am new in odoo. I am using Odoo 8. It is under stock/stock_report.xml. I inherit one menu option (top dropdown menu) report in my new module. Now I want to show it based on some condition. More clearly, `menu="False"` if `('state', '==', 'assigned')` otherwise, `menu="True"`.

How can I write this in menu. I have tried like following way. But it does not work. Or, if there any other way to do. I must have to do it by inheriting.

```xml
<report
            string="Picking test"
            id="stock.action_report_picking"
            model="stock.picking"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="stock.report_picking"
            file="stock.report_picking"
            menu="{'False':['|',('state', '==', 'assigned')]}"
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that but you can work a round hide that report from the menu

```
   menu = "False"
```

And use a button to print that report with button you can use `attrs` to hide that button `[('state', '=', 'assigned')]`